# ECDC/PHE covid data clash

Tags: covid-19, coronavirus, healthcare-data, database, covid-19-datasets

12 April's new daily confirmed cases for UK seem to be dramatically different:

- ECDC says 8719 (https://ourworldindata.org/grapher/daily-cases-covid-19?country=GBR), while
- PHE says 84279-78991=5288 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020_coronavirus_pandemic_in_the_United_Kingdom#Timeline).

Now, I know that there could be something different in the definition of "new cases" or in the way they are measured. 
What is exactly the difference due to?

Also, ECDC's data is quite alarming because it's a dramatic jump looking at ECDC's same data for the past days.

Comment: The daily number can (stochastically) go up or down. It helps more to look at the cumulative number and the tangent to this latter curve.

Comment: Sometimes based on methodology change or backlogs there can be sharp daily spike. I don't know if that's the case here, but at least for China, France, and the US there have been such "anomalies". See e.g. https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/47259/which-data-are-correct-for-the-number-of-sars-cov2-positive-tests-in-france-on-a

Comment: or https://www.npr.org/sections/coronavirus-live-updates/2020/04/08/829506542/after-deaths-at-home-in-nyc-officials-plan-to-count-many-as-covid-19 I'm pretty sure there was an article about a past spike in NYC on similar [reporting] grounds, but I can't seem to find it [again] right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### PHE

12-4-2020 84279 - 78891 = 5388

11-4-2020 78891 - 70272 = 8619

10-4-2020 70272 - 65077 = 5195

#### ECDC

12-4-2020 8719

11-4-2020 5195

10-4-2020 4344

It looks like the PHE data is a day ahead of the ECDC data